# XML Schema define custom named nodes down to specific level

Tags: xml, xsd

I've got an XML file which consists of a root node with a defined name "IDTree". This node shall contain exactly three levels of descendents with **undefined** names, because I need to use XPath in an application to beautifully address specific values in this XML file.

Example:

```
<IDTree>
  <Foofoo id="0x00">
    <Foobar id="0x00">
      <Boofar id="0x00" />
      <Fasfoo id="0x01" />
      <Farfoo id="0x02" />
    </Foobar>
    <Foobas id="0x01">
      <Bas id="0x00" />
      <Bar id="0x01" />
      <Foo id="0x02" />
    </Foobas>
  </Foofoo>
</IDTree>
```

I need to address these nodes by using XPath like "/IDTree/Foofoo/Foobas/Bar" to convert them into three values like 0x00 0x01 0x01.

The data stored in this XML file is somehow "dynamic". That is it will probably get extended, edited or otherwise altered by adding, moving, deleting nodes with unspecified names within these three levels.

Below the third level however nodes shall have defined names. Every node on the third level below the root node shall have zero or one child node with the name "Description" which in turn shall have subnode with the names "ShortDesc" and "Field". "Field" on the other hand shall have zero to many fields named "Value".

All child nodes of the root node shall have attributes with defined names. All nodes on levels 1 - 3 below the root node with unspecified names must have an 'id' attribute. The nodes with defined names below level 3 all shall have defined attributes depending on their type.

Question is, how do I specify all these requirements and options in a XML Scheme?

Comment: Off hand, I don't see any way to do what you describe in XSD.  Your design is so unlike the use case for which XSD was developed that I have to ask:  what benefit do you expect to derive from having an XSD schema for your vocabulary design?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I kinda know... ummh, it's just to make the XML file editable by team members that aren't that much used to XML by supporting an eye candy graphical interface. Theoretically, I could write one myself. But I actually don't have the time for that, other priorities that is, and there already are plenty of pretty decent graphical editors out there that just need a valid XSD to work. But if it's not possible, I suppose, I really have to create a specialized editor myself...